# Pulling Listbox data to sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

listbox is being populated by JSON data correctly into the listboz. When I then try to take the listbox`enter code here` data and then populate the sqlite database when running it is not writing to the db.

```
                foreach (var closeout in deseiralizeObject.Reports)

                CloseoutslListBox.Items.Add($"{closeout.CloseoutID}, {closeout.Desc}, {closeout.Start},{closeout.End}");

            for (int i = 0; i < CloseoutslListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                CloseoutslListBox.SetSelected(i, true);
            }
            GetCloseout vc = new GetCloseout();

            vc.CloseoutID = CloseoutslListBox.Text;
            vc.Desc = CloseoutslListBox.Text;
            vc.Start = CloseoutslListBox.Text;
            vc.End = CloseoutslListBox.Text;


            SqliteDataAccess.SaveAPIData(p);

            CloseoutslListBox.Text = "";
```

And my sqlite side

```
       public static void SaveAPIData(GetCloseout close)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            cnn.Execute("insert into VersiCloseOuts (CloseoutID, Desc, Start, End) values (@CloseoutID, @Desc, @Start, @End)", close);
        }
    }
```

Sqlite table fields are being populated by all the data in a single field and not broken down by the individual parts that is being extracted from the JSON.
From this section of code:

```
    vc.CloseoutID = CloseoutslListBox.Text;
        vc.Desc = CloseoutslListBox.Text;
        vc.Start = CloseoutslListBox.Text;
        vc.End = CloseoutslListBox.Text;
```

And the Sqlite table field

```
2020112501, 11/25/2020 #01 Wed, 2020-11-24T20:01:55.000-08:00,2020-11-25T16:49:40.000-08:00
```

Comment: Your code is passing `p`. Did you mean to pass `vc`?

Comment: Using dapper also?

Comment: I wouldn't think Dapper would fail silently, assuming p is an instance of another class that does not have any matching properties. There is more to this than what you're saying.

Comment: Yes it needed to be switched to vc and using dapper